# Store a query statement inside database

Tags: android, mysql, sql

the question is very simple, while developing in android I have a query to INSERT some data in the database:

```
writeDB("INSERT INTO procedencia (procedencia) VALUES(" +
                                    "'" + procedencia + "'" +
                                    ");");
```

my writeDB method looks like this.

```
public void writeDB(String query) {
        dbWrite.execSQL(query);
}
```

everything works fine until now. The only problem is that I need to store the queryString into another table. 
something like this.

```
dbWrite.execSQL("INSERT INTO Q (query) VALUES (" +
                "'" + query + "'" +
                ");");
```

that is where the problem starts because it is causing problems. what can I do, is there any method or library like the one of php ->prepare(QUERY);?

Comment: Can you show any error log what you are getting?

Comment: the error is because this line:
the ' and " are closing before the whole statement is executed.

Comment: You should store it as a stored procedure, not as a column of ordinary data.

Comment: Well its not intended to be used as a procedure. The usage of this data is because when the user clicks a button every statement will be send to a server then the server will execute the statements. Is there a way to do this with procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple working example of how you can store your query statement inside `SQLite` database.

```
/**
 * inside the class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper
 * */

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
    value.put("Query", query); 
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert("YourTableName", null, value);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
```